# Do modifications in Octopus processes affects previously created releases?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, octopus-deploy

I have a question regarding **Octopus Deploy** processes.

The setup I'm currently using is Team Foundation Server -> Azure DevOps -> Octopus Deploy.

For example, I have already created an Octopus release, and deployed using Octopus process A,B and C (for Dev, Stage and Prod environments). Those processes take the Azure DevOps build form the main TFS branch.

After that, I started working on multiple features, and needed to deploy from a different TFS branch that has only one of the new features. For this I crated a new TFS branch with the changes, a new Azure DevOps pipeline that builds from this branch, and finally created another 3 Octopus processes A2, B2 and C2, also for Dev, Stage and Prod environments, that uses the new DevOps pipeline (in new Steps). Then, I deployed only the new features to the desired environment(by deselecting the old processes in the Octopus process tab, and selecting the new ones). Using Octopus like this, we are able to use the main and secondary branches to develop different features on our team. I made a diagram because otherwise its not very clear:

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaQDb.png)

Now, what I want to do is **redeploy the first release** (the one built from the main TFS branch, I will need to deploy this package to Prod). Do I need to switch the Octopus processes again, or the fact that the release was created when the processes A, B , and C were selected means that those are the ones that will be used? There wont be any problem when deploying to the other environments (Dev->Stage->Prod) because the processes selected now are A2, B2 and C2?

I have already read and in [the octopus documentation](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/releases) it says that

> When you create a release, you are capturing the deployment process and all the associated assets (packages, scripts, variables, etc) as they existed at that time.

So does this also include the Steps? Its safely to assume that I can continue deploying like this, or creating a new Release is recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, It never affects the old release when you change the octopus process.

You can still follow the old process using that old release.

It saved the version of the process with release information.

Comment: Thanks you for the clarification!